# Export button is not showing on Bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm using this website as a reference - https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/extensions/export/#showexport. The problem here is that the export button is not showing, I've already re-arranged the scripts and nothing is happening. I settled the data-show-export as true - nothing happened. I added the Jquery script first, Popper second and finally Bootstrap, and nothing. Now, I don't know what to do, may anyone help to see if I'm doing anything wrong? Thank you!

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>TSS BRA Automation For Unbilled</title>

      <!-- Fonts -->
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <!-- Table loading -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/placeholder-loading/dist/css/placeholder-loading.min.css">
      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/css/bootstrap/bootstrap-table.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.21.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Style CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/css/main-styles.css">
      <!-- Style SCSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/scss/style.css">
      <!-- Resizable property -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/jquery-resizable-columns@0.2.3/dist/jquery.resizableColumns.css">
      <!-- Export property -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
   </head>

   <body class="main-layout">
      <!-- <div class="loader_bg">
         <div class="loader"><img src="static/styles/static/images/loading.gif" alt="#" /></div>
      </div> -->
      <header>
         <div class="header_bg">
            <div class="header">
               <a href="index.html"><img class="logo"
                     src="https://i.postimg.cc/bwWpnryh/images-removebg-preview.png"
                     alt="#" />
               </a>
            </div>

            <section class="banner_main">
               <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="row d_flex">
                     <div class="text-bg">
                        <h1><strong>Welcome to<br/></strong> TSS BRA Automation
                              for Unbilled</h1>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </section>
               </div>
            </header>

            <main>
               <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="card">
                           <div class="card-header">
                              <div class="center">
                                 <i class="fa-solid fa-upload"></i>
                                 <strong>Upload your files</strong>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="cardBody card-block">
                              <div id="message" class="d-none">
                              </div>
                              <form method="POST" action="/"
                                 enctype="multipart/form-data"
                                 class="form-horizontal" id="form">
                                 <div class="row form-group">
                                    <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
                                       <div class="control-group" id="fields">
                                          <label class="control-label"
                                             for="formFile">
                                             Chis Ativo
                                          </label>
                                          <label class="control-label2"
                                             for="formFile2">
                                             Gis Mensal
                                          </label>
                                          <div class="controls">
                                             <div class="entry_1 upload-input">
                                                <input class="form-control input"
                                                   name="file_1" type="file"
                                                   id="activeChisForm"
                                                   accept="xlsx" required>
                                             </div>
                                             <div class="entry_2 upload-input">
                                                <input class="form-control input"
                                                   name="file_2" type="file"
                                                   id="gisForm" accept="xlsx"
                                                   required>
                                             </div>
                                          </div>

                                          <button class="submitButton"
                                             type="submit" value="Submit"
                                             id="bsubmit" style="--content:
                                             'Upload';">
                                             <div class="left"></div>
                                             Upload
                                             <div class="right"></div>
                                          </button>
                                          <a target="_blank" href="#"><svg
                                                style="width:2em;height:2em;position:fixed;top:1em;left:1em;opacity:.8;"
                                                viewBox="0 0 24 24"></svg></a>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </form>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                     <div class="card">
                        <div class="cardBody card-block">
                           <div id="toolbar" class="select">
                              <select class="form-control">
                                <option value="">Export Basic</option>
                                <option value="all">Export All</option>
                                <option value="selected">Export Selected</option>
                              </select>
                            </div>
                           <table
                              id="table"
                              data-toolbar="#toolbar"
                              data-search="true"
                              data-search-highlight="true"
                              data-show-toggle="true"
                              data-show-fullscreen="true"
                              data-show-columns="true"
                              data-show-columns-toggle-all="true"
                              data-detail-view="true"
                              data-show-export="true"
                              data-export-data-type="all"
                              data-click-to-select="false"
                              data-detail-formatter="detailFormatter"
                              data-minimum-count-columns="2"
                              data-show-pagination-switch="true"
                              data-pagination="true"
                              data-id-field="id"
                              data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, all]"
                              data-url="https://examples.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/bootstrap_table/data"
                              data-side-pagination="server"
                              data-response-handler="responseHandler"
                              data-resizable="true"
                              data-show-search-clear-button="true"
                              data-show-copy-rows="true"
                              data-loading-template="loadingTemplate">
                           </table>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </main>
      
      <footer>
         <div class="footer">
            <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                     <a target=”_blank”
                        href="https://w3.ibm.com/w3publisher/amq2c-kaizen"><img
                           class="citech"
                           src="https://i.postimg.cc/y8qRPTs7/citechlogo.png">
                     </a>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </footer>

      <!-- Jquery -->
      <script src="static/styles/js/jquery-3.6.2.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="static/styles/js/jquery.base64.js"></script>
      <!-- Popper -->
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootsztrap-table@1.21.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap Table -->
      <!-- Sweet alert -->
      <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
      <!-- Scripts -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="static/styles/js/script.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="static/styles/js/custom.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="static/styles/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
      <script>$.browser = {}</script>
      <!-- Resizable Columns -->
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery-resizable-columns@0.2.3/dist/jquery.resizableColumns.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/extensions/resizable/bootstrap-table-resizable.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(function(){
            $("table").resizableColumns();
         });
      </script>
      <!-- Bootstrap export -->
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/tableexport.jquery.plugin/tableExport.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tableexport.jquery.plugin@1.10.21/libs/jsPDF/jspdf.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tableexport.jquery.plugin@1.10.21/libs/jsPDF-AutoTable/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
      
   </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I would guess the problem is with your library versions.  You load Bootstrap-Table v1.14 which says it is for Bootstrap versions 2 and 3, but then you load a mix of Bootstrap 4.0 and 4.6.  All of these libraries are over 4 years old.  The current versions are Bootstrap v5 and Bootstrap-Table 1.21.

Comment: I updated and everything stopped working :(

Comment: I looked at this more.  The code is loading mismatched library versions and even multiple versions of the same libraries.  You need to fix these problems and provide a code sample that allows others to duplicate the problem. It might be worthwhile to create a simpler page with only the libraries and html required to generate the table. And once you have that working then start adding the other parts of the original page.